Adjusting Minimap Camera Viewport Indicator to Account for Occlusion of Camera by UI
I am working on a 2D RTS game in Unity. One thing I want to represent is a minimap indicator that shows the camera's viewport. I got it working, but it doesn't reflect how the camera is occluded by the top and bottom UI bars. I want the minimap indicator to only show what the camera sees, i.e., everything not occluded by the top and bottom bars. Here's what it looks like without the top and bottom bars taken into account. The yellow transparent square is the indicator. 
Here's the code I got:
public class Minimap : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    [SerializeField] Camera mainCamera;           
    [SerializeField] CameraController mainCameraController;
    [SerializeField] Camera minimapCamera;         
    [SerializeField] RectTransform minimap;     
    [SerializeField] RectTransform minimapIndicator;
    [SerializeField] RectTransform topBar, bottomBar;
    [SerializeField] Canvas mainCanvas;

    [SerializeField] Vector2 minimapWorldSize;

    void Start()
    {
        float minimapHeight = minimapCamera.orthographicSize * 2;
        float minimapWidth = minimapHeight * minimapCamera.aspect;
        minimapWorldSize = new Vector2(minimapWidth, minimapHeight);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdatePositionAndSize();
    }

    void UpdatePositionAndSize()
    {
        Vector3 mainCameraPos = mainCamera.transform.position;

        float mainCameraHeight = mainCamera.orthographicSize * 2;
        float mainCameraWidth = mainCameraHeight * mainCamera.aspect;

        float normalizedX = (mainCameraPos.x - minimapCamera.transform.position.x + (minimapWorldSize.x / 2)) / minimapWorldSize.x;
        float normalizedY = (mainCameraPos.y - minimapCamera.transform.position.y + (minimapWorldSize.y / 2)) / minimapWorldSize.y;

        Vector2 newAnchoredPosition = new Vector2(
            (normalizedX * minimap.rect.width) - minimap.rect.width / 2,
            (normalizedY * minimap.rect.height) - minimap.rect.height / 2
        );

        minimapIndicator.anchoredPosition = newAnchoredPosition;

        float indicatorWidth = (mainCameraWidth / minimapWorldSize.x) * minimap.rect.width;
        float indicatorHeight = (mainCameraHeight / minimapWorldSize.y) * minimap.rect.height;

        minimapIndicator.sizeDelta = new Vector2(indicatorWidth, indicatorHeight);
    }

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(minimap, eventData.position, eventData.pressEventCamera, out Vector2 localPoint);

        float normalizedX = (localPoint.x + minimap.rect.width / 2) / minimap.rect.width;
        float normalizedY = (localPoint.y + minimap.rect.height / 2) / minimap.rect.height;

        float targetX = (normalizedX * minimapWorldSize.x) - (minimapWorldSize.x / 2) + minimapCamera.transform.position.x;
        float targetY = (normalizedY * minimapWorldSize.y) - (minimapWorldSize.y / 2) + minimapCamera.transform.position.y;

        mainCameraController.OverridePosition(new Vector2(targetX, targetY));
    }
}

I've tried calculating the visible camera height and adjusting the y-position of the indicator, but I always get a negative height for the indicator. I am unsure how to convert the UI units into world units for the visible height calculation and then convert it into the appropriate units for the minimap. Here is what I tried:
   void UpdatePositionAndSize()
   {
       Vector3 mainCameraPos = mainCamera.transform.position;

       float mainCameraHeight = mainCamera.orthographicSize * 2;
       float mainCameraWidth = mainCameraHeight * mainCamera.aspect;

       float topBarHeight = topBar.rect.height;
       float bottomBarHeight = bottomBar.rect.height;
       float visibleCameraHeight = mainCameraHeight - topBarHeight - bottomBarHeight;

       float normalizedX = (mainCameraPos.x - minimapCamera.transform.position.x + (minimapWorldSize.x / 2)) / minimapWorldSize.x;
       float normalizedY = (mainCameraPos.y - minimapCamera.transform.position.y + (visibleCameraHeight / 2)) / minimapWorldSize.y;

       Vector2 newAnchoredPosition = new Vector2(
           (normalizedX * minimap.rect.width) - minimap.rect.width / 2,
           (normalizedY * minimap.rect.height) - minimap.rect.height / 2
       );
       minimapIndicator.anchoredPosition = newAnchoredPosition;

       float indicatorWidth = (mainCameraWidth / minimapWorldSize.x) * minimap.rect.width;
       float indicatorHeight = (visibleCameraHeight / minimapWorldSize.y) * minimap.rect.height;
       minimapIndicator.sizeDelta = new Vector2(indicatorWidth, indicatorHeight);
   }

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Will this game ever be built for different platforms?

@agone I don't know. I am just focusing on PC in mind for now.
